# +1 and -1 Increment button to a google sheets cell with a formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a charterer sheet for a tabletop RPG. The cell I'm adding to has an active formula. When i run the script bellow, the cell successfully updates with the +1 value but the formula is gone.

I would like to keep the formula and use a +1 button to add 1 to the total value of the cell. I have little to no experience coding, most of what ive found is from Google or Youtube.

```
function soakup() { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Charecter!B11').setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Charecter!B11').getValue() +1);}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. In your script, `Charecter!B11` is used. In this case, only the cell "B11" in the sheet of `Charecter` is used. Is this the same with your actual situation? 2. For example, how about putting `="Existing formula" + B12` to the cell "B11" and increasing `+1` or `-1` to the cell `B12`? By this, `B11` can be increase `+1` or `-1`  by modifying your script a little.

Comment: Can you show the formula you have in the cell and show how you want the formula to look like after the increment?

Comment: I will try your suggestion today @Tanaike. @ziganotschka Here is the formula `=IFERROR(vlookup(Charecter!B3,Tables!C22:N29,2,False)+Equipment!C32,"Select Species")` I would like it to look like `=IFERROR(vlookup(Charecter!B3,Tables!C22:N29,2,False)+Equipment!C32,"Select Species")+1`. And incrementally add "+1" as the button is pressed"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to wait for your result. By the way, in your situation, when several clicks of `+1` and `-1`, can I ask you about the result you expect? For example, those are like `=formula()+3` or `=formula()+1+1-1+1+1`.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `getFormula()` and `setFormula()` instead of `getValue()` and `setValue()`
- Define "+1" as a string that you add to your formula

**Sample:**

```
function soakup() { 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Charecter!B11').setFormula(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Charecter!B11').getFormulaR1C1()+"+1");
}
```